# CSS issue in table

Tags: css, html

I have done a lot of research before posting it in here. So, here I got few imperfections.[my link](http://eminli.net/test)

**Question:** In the last tab which is supposed to be a contact info tab, how do I make those two tables to get close to each other? I will take borders afterwards. But how do I make them get close and centered?

I put them under table, did not work. Then tried to use division, still is not working. what should I chance in the css file?

Thats it for now. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you have two different questions, post them separately. Question 1 has nothing to do with the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Question 2
 I want to say that in css replace `float:right` for `sag` div

Comment: Nice, it worked! and how do I center them into the middle? do you know?

Answer (score 0):

```
    .contact-info {
        width:98%; 
        margin:1%;
    }
#sol {
    float:left;
    text-align:left; 
    margin-left:290px; 
    margin-right:auto; 
    width:200px;
    }
#sag {
    float:left;
    text-align:left; 
    margin-left:auto; 
    margin-right:auto; 
    width:200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your second question I want to tell you that in `css` replace `float:right` for `sag div` and to place them in the center of the page just add in your css just add
`#contact-info { width:250px; 
margin: 0 auto;
}`
Hope this will help you!